# Explain the terminal velocity equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, velocity, drag, homework-and-exercises

As explained by [Method 1 on WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Terminal-Velocity), the equation for Terminal Velocity is:

$$ V_T = \sqrt{2 \times m \times g \over ρ \times A \times C} $$

Some parts of this equation are self explanatory, and some parts I now understand thanks to the wiki how ($V_T$ is Velocity, $m$ is mass, $g$ is gravity). But then I get to these pro numerals and get wildly confused as they make no sense to me: $ρ$, $A$, and $C$. My assumptions tell me that $ρ$ is the density of the object, $A$ is the area the object takes up, and $C$ is the [wind resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29).

Can someone explain what each pro numeral actually means?

Comment: IMHO, if your interest is terminal velocity just check the regular differential equation given in the form : $mx''=-mg+bx'^2$

Comment: In your first link (to WikiHow), there is a list of variables in the formula where the meaning of each one is described. What's not sufficient about the explanations given there?

Comment: David, that equation confused me just as much, Year10 physics student.

@DavidZ, $ρ$ is the density *around* the object, and $A$ is... non-understandable? would $A$ be how far the object still has until it hits another object/surface? As for $C$, I understand that now. That depends on the shape of the object, correct?

Comment: I'm not talking about any equation. I'm talking about a list of explanations of the variables. For instance "ρ = the density of the fluid the object is falling through." What's not clear about that? Anyway, if you're confused about those definitions, try checking other sources like Wikipedia, HyperPhysics, and anything else you have available. If you still can't find a reasonable explanation, _then_ you ask here, and make sure to ask precisely what you want, for example "What does $A$ mean in the formula for terminal velocity?"

Comment: It was to @David, you both have **extremely** similar names. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reading is correct, aside from the "Wind Resistance". It is a "drag co-efficient" and is a "fudge factor" so that $A\,C$ is the area of the "effective face" that the falling object presents to the fluid. It measures how much different the effective area is from the actual cross-sectional area.

Another way to think of it is as a "tweak" factor to mop up the errors of approximations in a simple-minded derivation of the [ram drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_pressure) on a body moving through a fluid. Here's how it works. To understand the ram pressure, which arises particularly for supersonic objects, witness the object is just shoving fluid out of its way, and the latter flows off at some high angle to the trajectory. Think of a stationary object with a flat leading surface with a high speed flow around it. Think of a hosepipe's output blasting against a flat wall, for example, and think of your hose big enough that the flow exactly covers the wall.

Fluid striking the flat surface gets deflected almost at right angles to the incoming flow. In unit time, the mass of fluid being deflected is $\rho\,A\,v$, where $A$ is the area of the wall. The initial momentum is $m_f\,v=\rho\,A\,v^2$ ($m_f$ is the fluid mass), in a direction towards the wall. After deflexion, if the flow is symmetrical, the momentums of the particles running radially at right angles to the wall all sum to a nett vector momentum of nought. Therefore, the impulse per unit time (change in fluid momentum per unit time) is $\rho\,A\,v^2$. This then is the force.

So, if we have our object presenting a cross-sectional area $A$ falling through a fluid, the force of gravity will be balanced when $m\,g=\rho\,A\,v^2$, which you can re-arrange to get something like your formula: $v = \sqrt{\frac{m\,g}{\rho\,A}}$.

However, there are imperfections in this argument. Depending on the surface's shape, the deflected fluid will not run of at right angles. It will be some angle between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Also, at steady state, the object's cross section will be effectively bigger as its disturbances to the fluid propagate outward. So we need a "fudge factor" for the area $A$ to account for these imperfections. This fudge factor is $2\,C$ (why it isn't $C$ is for historical reasons: one likes to talk about drag co-efficients as a fraction of the affected fluid's kinetic energy, so we talk about measured drag as a fraction of $\frac{1}{2}\,A\,\rho\,v^2$).

Those Wiki Hows look like a good references if you understand the meaning of everything and just want to jog your memory of the right formulas. But always go to the relevant Wikipedia page or search more widely for online physics course notes for deeper understanding.

Comment: So $C$ is how much resistance there is to the object, which must be taken from a certain value? Because if the water runs off at right angles, then $C = 0$. How do you find $C$? That seems to be the main thing that is tripping me up right now...

Comment: @mastercork889 At right angles, $C=2$. $C$ depends on the shape and texture of the body in question. It is experimentally or numerically found for each new shape / texture.